# Proving $0<|x-a|<\delta$ =>$|g(x) > |M|/2$ (Epsilon-Delta problem)

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

As the title says I have to prove that:

if $\lim_{x\to a}$  $g(x) = M$

Where $M \not= 0$,

Show that there exist a number $\delta >0$ such that:

$0<|x-a|<\delta$ =>$|g(x)| > |M|/2$

How do I even approach this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might have made a mistake in the statement of your problem. It is not trus as stated, for example you can take the the function $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Do you mean $M >0$?

Comment: other than I used $==$ instaed of $ \not=$ the statement is identical to the one in my book.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the limit, we have that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon.$ Or $M-\epsilon<g(x)<M+\epsilon.$ Assuming $M>0$ take $\epsilon =M$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $|x-a|<\delta$  then we have that $g(x)>M/2$.

Comment: Hmm. But I don't really understand the reasoning for taking $\epsilon = M$  and why would that mean $|g(x)| > M/2$?

Comment: Am I allowed to just take $\epsilon = M$?

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind the statement $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=M$$ is the following. When your point $x$ is really close to $a$, $g(x)$ is really close to $M$. In particular, if $M \neq 0$ you know there exist an $\epsilon_0 >0,$ maybe very small, such that 
$$\vert M \vert -\epsilon_0 > \dfrac{\vert M \vert}{2}$$
which implies that $\epsilon_0 < \vert M \vert /2.$ Moreover, by the definition of limit, you know that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exist $\delta >0$ such that if $0 < \vert x-a \vert <\delta,$ then $ \vert g(x) - M \vert =\vert g(x) - \lim_{x \to a}g(x) \vert < \epsilon.$

Therefore, you can pick $\delta_0 > 0$ such that if $0 < \vert x-a \vert <\delta_0$, then 
$$\vert M \vert - \vert g(x) \vert < \vert g(x) - M \vert <\epsilon_0 < \vert M \vert /2.$$
This implies that $\vert g(x) \vert > \vert M \vert/2.$

Comment: I think i'm having a little hard time following the reasoning. 

From $|g(x) -M| < \epsilon$

Are you trying to manipulate/control the bound of $\epsilon$ to prove
$|g(x)| > |M|/2$?

Comment: If you take any $\epsilon < \vert M \vert/2,$ then it means that when $g(x)$ is at distance less than $\epsilon$ from $M,$ $g(x) > \vert M \vert /2$